# Applying scipy.stats.gaussian_kde to 3D point cloud

Tags: scipy

I have a set of about 33K (x,y,z) points in a csv file and would like to convert this to a grid of density values using scipy.stats.gaussian_kde. I have not been able to find a way to convert this point cloud array into an appropriate input format for the gaussian_kde function (and then take the output of this and convert it into a density value grid). Can anyone provide sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with some comments which may be of use. `gaussian_kde` wants the data and points to be row stacked, ie. (# ndim, # num values), as per the docs. In your case you would `row_stack([x, y, z])` such that the shape is `(3, 33000)`.

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# simulate some data
n = 33000
x = np.random.randn(n)
y = np.random.randn(n) * 2

# data must be stacked as (# ndim, # n values) as per docs.
data = np.row_stack((x, y))

# perform KDE
kernel = gaussian_kde(data)

# create grid over which to evaluate KDE
s = np.linspace(-8, 8, 128)
grid = np.meshgrid(s, s)
# again KDE needs points to be row_stacked
grid_points = np.row_stack([g.ravel() for g in grid])

# evaluate KDE and reshape result correctly
Z = kernel(grid_points)
Z = Z.reshape(grid[0].shape)

# plot KDE as image and overlay some data points
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.matshow(Z, extent=(s.min(), s.max(), s.min(), s.max()))
ax.plot(x[::10], y[::10], 'w.', ms=1, alpha=0.3)
ax.set_xlim(s.min(), s.max())
ax.set_ylim(s.min(), s.max())
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much! I am currently running a revised version of this code on my data. So far I notice that the kernel is generated quickly but evaluating it on a 200x200x200 grid is much slower than the scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter code I have been running before. I am very curious to see the difference.

Comment: Actually, it was a 400x400x400 grid and I think there was something wrong with the meshgrid command.. Now the gridpoints fed to the kernel are [[  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]
 [  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]
 [  0   1   2 ... 397 398 399]] whick looks OK, but the result returned is just a 1D grid with shape (400,)

Comment: Yes you want to flatten your grid points, which is done in this line `grid_points = np.row_stack([g.ravel() for g in grid])`

Comment: I found FFTKDE to be much faster but I ran gausian_kde on my data for several days anyway because of its automatic bandwidth selection. All looks good now.